How to launch link with "itms-appss" scheme?
How can i launch urls like "itms-appss://apps.apple.com/us/app/discord-chat-for-games/id985746746" in Flutter?  It is expected to launch the app store and show discord for downloading.
Note: I tried to launch with url_launcher package but It's canLaunch method gives false also launching doesn't happen.

Replace your URL scheme "itms-appss" to "itms-apps" and try again with your code.
